# Moving from HTTP based basicHttpBinding to HTTPS

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, basichttpbinding

I'm using basicHttpBinding with custom behaviors in my .NET 4.5 project.

The new request is to authenticate users so I would like to switch https. What is the easiest way for this?

How should I do this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a binding setting the [security mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731884%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Transport` which means HTTPS in this case:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
       <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Then change the endpoint url to be HTTPS and you are set.

Also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648431.aspx) old but detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you. And where can I read out username and password? With a custom validator?

Comment: My bad. You should be fine with `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: Yes, or with Windows authentication. It is up to you. Not sure if you have to write own bindings for custom authentication methods. I do think so.